# How to display Windows-1252 (ansi) on a utf8 page?

Tags: php, html

I'm running php scripts on a wordpress page, wordpress automatically sets the whole page to utf8. My source data is in Windows-1252 and I am able to display it mostly correctly by just encoding it into utf8.

However characters betweeen 0x7F and 0xA2 do not display at all?

http://www.alanwood.net/demos/ansi.html

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php

Comment: "do not display at all" means what? A square box shows instead? A blank space shows? No byte is transmitted over HTTP at all?

Comment: Just nothing is there, even in the html source. If I don't run it through utf8_encode() a diamond with a question mark appears.

Answer (score 0):

You can use iconv or mb-convert-encoding. utf8_encode assumes input is ISO-8859-1. Maybe that's why some characters disappear, as Win 1252 isn't ISO 8859-1.